# How to get Wepay Ipn Callback Uri

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am testing wepay subscription payment using woocommerce. Now i am Struggle in wepay Ipn Callback uri .
i want How to get Callback uri in  wepay  response .

I'm get all subscription id , amount, state but Callback uri only i get like this  ["callback_uri"]=> string(0) "".

this is my code

```
     global $woocommerce;
     require 'wepay.php';          

        $order = new WC_Order('39');
        $order->reduce_order_stock();
              $api_name = $this->get_option('api_username');
              $api_client = $this->get_option('api_clientid');
              $api_mailid = $this->get_option('api_emailid');
              $redirect_uri = $this->get_option('redirect_uri');
              $client_secretid = $this->get_option('api_client_secret');
              $access_token = $this->get_option('api_access_token');  
              $account_id   = $this->get_option('api_accountid');


              wepay::useStaging($api_client, $client_secretid);
              $wepay = new WePay($access_token);

            $resp = $wepay->request('subscription', array(
            'subscription_id'  => '1797054990',

));
```

Tell me if anyone use wepay .

thanks

Comment: Please post your code example. And read first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to specify the callback_uri; it's not something that WePay provides for you. How to do that using WooCommerce, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

1. WePay sends as a post request.
2. Try using requestBin to first check what's the payload data.
3. WePay will only send you the entity: entityID, not the full data, you have to call the WePay API again to get the status, like 
   [WePay payload data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEyaD.png)

Answer (score 0):

This code is 100% working for me. Hope it will be help for you.

```
 <?php

        require 'wepay.php';

        if (!empty($_POST['checkout_id'])) {
            $thecheckoutid = $_POST['checkout_id'];
        }

        // application settings

        $client_id = "<Your Client ID>";
        $client_secret = "<Your Client Secret>";
        $access_token = "<Your Client Token>";
        $account_id = "<Your Accout ID>";

        /**
         * Initialize the WePay SDK object
         */
        Wepay::useStaging($client_id, $client_secret);
        $wepay = new WePay($access_token);

        /**
         * Make the API request to get the checkout_uri
         *
         */
        //$thecheckoutid = 672117563;
        //$thecheckoutid = 1487059142;
        try {
            $checkout = $wepay->request('checkout', array(
                    'checkout_id' => $thecheckoutid, // ID of the account that you want the money to go to
                )
            );
        } catch (WePayException $e) { // if the API call returns an error, get the error message for display later
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($checkout);
        ///some things you might want to use. Delete this stuff otherwise///
        print '<br /><br />';
        print $checkout->short_description;
        print '<br /><br />';
        print $checkout->checkout_id;
        print '<br /><br />';
        print $checkout->reference_id;
        print '<br /><br />';
        print $checkout->gross;
        print '<br /><br />';
        print $checkout->payer->name;
        print '<br /><br />';
        print $checkout->payer->email;
        ////stop deleteing here///

        if ($checkout->state == "captured") {
            ///do something here
        } elseif ($checkout->state == "authorized") {
            ///do something here
        } elseif ($checkout->state == "cancelled") {
            ///do something here
        } elseif ($checkout->state == "refunded") {
            ///do something here
        } elseif ($checkout->state == "expired") {
            ///do something here
        }
        ?>
```